# How to subtract two dates without sunday in php

Tags: php, date, datetime

I want to subtract date with php or cakephp function,
example :

```
$date1 = '2016-05-19';
$date2 = '2016-05-23';
```

i want subtract dates without sunday, from example the result i want is 3, not 4, because 4 - 1 (sunday),

I already try with new Datetime php like this code,

```
$receipt_date   = new DateTime($air_way_bill['AirWayBill']['receive_date']);
$date           = new DateTime($air_way_bill['AirWayBill']['date']);
$difference     = $receipt_date->diff($date);
```

but the result is 4, how can i subtract with sunday between that range?
there is any step or way to doing what i mean?

thanks in advance...

[CASE CLOSED]:

True Answer :

```
// ============================= 1 ==================== //

$receipt_date   = new DateTime('2016-05-19');
$date           = new DateTime('2016-05-23');
$difference     = $receipt_date->diff($date);

$daterange = new DatePeriod($receipt_date, new DateInterval('P1D'), $date);

$count = 0;

foreach($daterange as $date){
    if(!($date->format("w"))) {
        $count++;
    }
}

echo ($difference->days)-$count;
```

// ================================================ //

```
// ============================= 2 ==================== //

function getSubtrackedDayCountWithoutSundaysButWithAllOtherDaysUsingDateTimeFunctions($startDate, $endDate)
{
    $days = $startDate->diff($endDate, true)->days;
    $sundays = intval($days / 7) + ($startDate->format('N') + $days % 7 >= 7);

    return intval($days)-Sundays;
```

}

// ======================================================== //

// ===================== This is my experiment =============== //

```
        $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($air_way_bill['AirWayBill']['date']));
        $receive_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($air_way_bill['AirWayBill']['receive_date']));

        $date_diff = round(abs(strtotime($receive_date) - strtotime($date)) / 86400);
        $weeks  = round(abs(strtotime($receive_date) - strtotime($date)) / (86400 * 7));

         echo $date_diff - $weeks;
```

// ======================================================== //

Thank you very much...

Comment: Use [chronos](https://github.com/cakephp/chronos) and then the easy to use API for sunday/weekday handling to do that.

Comment: wheter https://github.com/cakephp/chronos able to cakephp 2?

Comment: Of course, its a normal PHP package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find total days, and then find number of sundays in that range. Finally reduce those days from total days:

```
<?php    
$receipt_date   = new DateTime('2016-05-19');
$date           = new DateTime('2016-05-23');
$difference     = $receipt_date->diff($date);

$daterange = new DatePeriod($receipt_date, new DateInterval('P1D'), $date);

$count = 0;

foreach($daterange as $date){
    if(!($date->format("w"))) {
        $count++;
    }
}

echo ($difference->days)-$count;
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/qb0DJ)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a function to do what you are asking for.

```
function getSubtrackedDayCountWithoutSundaysButWithAllOtherDaysUsingDateTimeFunctions($startDate, $endDate)
{
    $days = $startDate->diff($endDate, true)->days;
    $sundays = intval($days / 7) + ($startDate->format('N') + $days % 7 >= 7);

    return intval($days)-$sundays;


}
```

Comment: thanks for your response ,I already try your answer, but $allDays return 1, $sundays also return 1, tell me if i was wrong while trying..

Comment: @OnesinusSaut I made a slight adjustment to fix the function

Comment: I got result 2 for $sunday, So when return iterator_count($allDays) - iterator_count($sunday), the result is 2, the sunday should 1 in that range, not 2

Comment: Edited to fix my answer.

Comment: I try it, but the result show error,  Call to a member function diff() on a non-object

Comment: I'm sorry, $startDate and $endDate that you mean maybe in newDateTime format, and I already tried your code and successfull, thanks for your response and answer...